# Nginx - Rewrite URL and keep basic auth

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, configuration

*Simplifying my problem, but this is basically what I'm trying to do:*

I have a website https://example.com

With files at some long path: https://example.com/foo/bar/this/that/file

I have an `/etc/hosts` file with an entry like:

```
1.2.3.4 ex.com
```

Where `1.2.3.4` is the IP address of `example.com`

I want to access `ex.com/file` and be redirected to https://example.com/foo/bar/this/that/file

---

**Problem**

If I use `proxy_pass`, I get an error because my SSL certificate is not valid for `ex.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ex.com;

    rewrite ^/(.*) /foo/bar/this/that/$1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://backend;
    }
}
```

If I use `return 301`, it seems to lose my basic auth credentials when I run curl

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ex.com;

    return 301 https://example.com/foo/bar/this/that$request_uri;
}
```

---

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to listen on a different hostname and redirect the full request to the correct URL?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue. `proxy_pass` throws an SSL handshake timeout as my nginx does not have a certificate authority to evaluate the target domain/server.

Rewrite or `return 301` does not work because the auth headers are stripped away. But strangely enough, if I try this with two nginx containers running in my localhost I was able to notice that the auth headers remained intact. The problem of auth headers vanishing comes up when trying to rewrite to a remote host.

I got over this problem by using a lambda that forcefully inserts auth info but it's not a good way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep auth from one URL to another.
SSL error is not related with you problem. If you don't have a valid SSL for ex.com you can't use ssl.

You have 2 options.

1. Setup basic auth at long address https://example.com/foo/bar/this/that/file
   In this case the password will be asked just after redirect.
2. Setup basic auth at short address `ex.com/file`. In this case password will be asked and after prompt user will be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

The servers are configured without SSL. I suppose you will be using `certbot` with its `nginx` plugin and it will handle the SSL stuff for you. Second, you have to put the authentication directives at the web server that will actually handle the authenticated user's request. I.e., if your servers are `ex.com` and `example.com` and the server with the restricted file is `example.com`, then any authentication configuration must be configured for `example.com`.

`proxy_pass` is different. If you use `proxy_pass` **instead** of `redirect` or `rewrite 301`, you may configure the authentication on the back end server.

As a final note, add SSL certificates for both domains, `ex.com` and `example.com`. Otherwise there will be an error when trying to read `https://ex.com/` and instead of a clean redirection you will see a big message warning you about the invalid certificate.